# How to configure hashicorp vault v1.2.3 to restrict login based on membership in an LDAP group?

Tags: ldap, hashicorp-vault

active directory LDAP configuration:

```
Key                             Value
---                             -----
binddn                          CN=BindVault,OU=my-ou,DC=ad,DC=xyz,DC=net
case_sensitive_names            true
certificate                     n/a
deny_null_bind                  true
discoverdn                      false
groupattr                       memberOf
groupdn                         DC=ad,DC=xyz,DC=net
groupfilter                     (&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName={{.Username}}))
insecure_tls                    false
starttls                        true
tls_max_version                 tls12
tls_min_version                 tls12
token_bound_cidrs               []
token_explicit_max_ttl          0s
token_max_ttl                   0s
token_no_default_policy         true
token_num_uses                  0
token_period                    0s
token_policies                  []
token_ttl                       0s
token_type                      default
upndomain                       n/a
url                             ldaps://ldaps.ad.xyz.net:636
use_pre111_group_cn_behavior    true
use_token_groups                true
userattr                        cn
userdn                          DC=ad,DC=xyz,DC=net
```

This works ok, in that when a user logs in, the query returns the groups that the user is a member of, and policies can be mapped to groups.

The problem is with users who are not a member of any ldap policy groups. Currently, these users are able to log in, but are denied access to everything because they are not assigned any policies. I would prefer that they can't log in at all.

Comment: I don't know if it will work but as long as the strategy for group membership resolution is searching for the authenticated user object and follow its `memberOf` attribute, you can try to exclude such users with the `groupfilter` itself by requiring any user to be member of at least one ldap group, ie. like any group mapped to a base policy, or like a `login` group (or role) that would list authorized-to-log-in users regardless of which vault policy they have been assigned. For example : `(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName={{.Username}})(memberOf=cn=login,OU=groups,DC=ad,DC=xyz,DC=net))`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution, I added the userfilter in the auth/ldap/config and configured it like this :

```
userfilter=“(&(objectClass=user)({{.UserAttr}}={{.Username}})(memberOf=cn=MySelectedGroup,cn=Users,dc=test,dc=com))”
```

So change the `memberOf=` at the end so that it matches your ldap group.

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an [open pull request](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/pull/11000) that will add a filter for users that can be used to allow access to only specified LDAP users. The pull request has passed all the automated checks and is awaiting review so will hopefully be added soon.